# Как вписать переменную из js внутрь тэга при использовании out.insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Например

```
var htmlCode = "<div> <span>переменная с текстом</span> + <span>переменная с текстом 2</span> </div>";
out.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', htmlCode);
```

p.s
это нужно чтобы потом у div'a можно было сделать flex и выровнять эти 2 span'a  с переменными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = "world";
var htmlCode = `<div> <span>${a}</span> <span>${b}</span> </div>`;
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло. я хз как тут закрыть вопрос, поэтому да

Comment: @ИльяKrike Через три-четыре минуты Вы сможете щелкнуть по "галочке" слева от ответа.